# How to get correct stacktrace in in case of async await in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, trace, stack-trace

I want to backtrace all the function calls made in async await function call. As most of the third party libraries uses promise based programming in node.js. Therefore backtracking of the actual function or user function which is responsible to do such call is so hard.
Please suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I’ve just tried this: you could create an error object and cache its stack trace, e.g. `const currentStackTrace = new Error();`, then use `currentStackTrace.stack` later.

Comment: What you want to achieve, can you explain it using the code